# postgresql hot updates table not working

Tags: performance, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  data1 character varying(255),
  data2 character varying(100000),
  double1 double precision,
  double2 double precision,
  id2 bigint
);
```

With index on `id2` (`id2` is foreign key).

and i have a query:

```
update my_table set double2 = :param where id2 = :id2;
```

This query uses index on `id2`, but it works very-very slow.

I expected that my query will use HOT updates, but it is not true.

I checked HOT updates by query:

```
SELECT pg_stat_get_xact_tuples_hot_updated('my_table'::regclass::oid);
```

and it always returns zero.

What am I doing wrong? How i can speedup my update query?

Version of postgres is 9.4.11.

UPD:
execution plan for update:

```
Update on my_table (cost=0.56..97681.01 rows=34633 width=90) (actual time=42082.915..42082.915 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using my_index on my_table (cost=0.56..97681.01 rows=34633 width=90) (actual time=0.110..330.563 rows=97128 loops=1)
         Output: id, data1, data2, 0.5::double precision, double1, id2, ctid
         Index Cond: (my_table.id2 = 379262689897216::bigint)
 Planning time: 1.246 ms
 Execution time: 42082.986 ms
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @Abelisto field "double2" is not indexed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i added execution plan, it is really make delete and insert. Have any idea why it happens? And can i disable mvcc for this table/transaction?

Comment: For HOT to be possible, PostgreSQL needs some amount of "free room at every page", which probably does not have. Look for `fillfactor` on the [`CREATE TABLE` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html). You can change it on an existing table, but won't find any difference until a sufficient amount of new rows has been inserted. To check if this helps (and you can) drop and recreate the table with a fillfactor of 75, and test for behaviour. [Or create a *copy* of your table with a fillfactor of 75]

Comment: @joanolo i created my_table2, set fillfactor to 75, inserted into new table data from old table, and it doestnot help (explain still output all columns in table and query pg_stat_get_xact_tuples_hot_updated still returns zero), but pg_stat_user_tables(column n_tup_upd, n_tup_hot_upd) show that sometimes it makes hot updates. Looks like it works. But i still have a question: can i make my update operation without mvcc? my_table is used for batch insert, batch select and batch update(on non indexed fields), these operations dont overlap in time on the same rows.

Comment: MVCC lies at the very foundation of PostgreSQL (as of now, at least). You cannot disable it, because there is not an alternative mechanism. If you need to update all the rows you have inserted, use fillfactor = 50. And if you need faster speed (at the cost of far less security, and losing the "D" guarantee in ACID), you can use [`unlogged tables`](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-performance-with-unlogged-tables-in-postgresql/).

Comment: Side note: HOT doesn't mean PostgreSQL only "touches" *one* column. HOT means your new row is deleted/inserted on the same page as the old one, which implies no need to update *indices*, and makes the `UPDATE` process faster altogether.

Comment: @joanolo thanks a lot!

Comment: You can do your operation without mvcc by `CREATE TABLE UNLOGGED`

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for HOT updates are:

- that you're updating only fields that aren't used in any indexes
- that the page that contains the row you're updating has extra space in it (fillfactor should be less than 100)

which based on your comments, you seem to be doing.

But one thing I noticed is that you said you're using `pg_stat_get_xact_tuples_hot_updated` to check if HOT updates are happening; be aware that this function returns only the number of HOT-updated rows *in the current transaction*, not from all time.  My guess is HOT updates are happening, but you used the wrong function to detect them.  If instead you use

`SELECT pg_stat_get_tuples_hot_updated('my_table'::regclass::oid);`

you can get the total number of HOT-updated rows for all time.